# SQL sort by containing string

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to sort by whether `'/us/'` is in a url. I currently have:

```
SELECT is_live, store_url from my_table where item_id = 1306085 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN store_url LIKE '%/us%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this, or is the above the only way? Conceptually, I'm looking for something a bit more readable, such as:

```
ORDER BY store_url.contains('/us/') DESC
```

Comment: You could [create a stored function or an user defined function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function.html) in MySQL.

Comment: @FrankJ thanks for the idea, that is a neat approach. Could you please show in an answer how that would be done with the above question?

Comment: You don't need the case to convert, true is treated as 1 and false as 0 for sorting purposes anyway. So `ORDER BY store_url LIKE '%/us%' DESC` should be fine... if you want it to look more like a function call you can use the [INSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) function... though that returns the actual found position, so you would want the ordering on `INSTR(...)=0 ASC` to prevent unwanted ranking by location in string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try this:

```
SELECT is_live, store_url from my_table where item_id = 1306085 
ORDER BY instr(store_url, '/us/');
```

or:

```
SELECT is_live, store_url from my_table where item_id = 1306085 
ORDER BY instr(store_url, '/us/') > 0 ;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d5c1/9)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html):

```
CREATE FUNCTION mycontains (s text, matchText VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
RETURN (CASE WHEN s LIKE CONCAT("%", matchText, "%") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

and use it like

```
SELECT is_live, store_url from my_table where item_id = 1306085 
ORDER BY mycontains(store_ul, "/us/") DESC
```

Note: There is already a contains function, I think it works with geometric objects, that is why I named this mycontains.

Comment: Have you heard of "Occam's razor": [Plurality must never be posited without necessity] ? Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor#Ockham   ;)

Comment: @MaxU: Well, your solution introduces a possibly not wanted order by returning the index, so you cannot further sort unless you amend your solution by equalizing all results greater than 0. So this does something different.

Comment: OP doesn't care whether each of those parts (0's and 1's) will be sorted or not... And your solution doesn't take into account slashes - `/us/` ;)

Comment: @MaxU: Since you amended your solution I agree that yours is the better way to go, and upvoted yours. Out of curiosity though, slashes seem to be working fine for me, what do you mean?

Comment: strings like `aaa_us_bbb` will be sorted incorrectly as OP wanted to check: "whether `/us/` is in a url". Now (after you edited it) it will work properly. So +1

Comment: @MaxU: Seems I have a different MySQL version than you, I don't get a false positive in that case... Just tried it out... Wonder what the difference is there... EDIT: Oh ok i missunderstood. TY :-) Again I think your solution is superior, I'm just following up on the suggestion I made in the comments above in the question.